# Auto Correlation in Time Series

Tags: python, time-series, correlation, trend, autocorrelation

I have been trying to Understand correlation and tried it on my project and need help interpreting for a my case and in general.

I have the following results but finding it hard to interpret.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNT6U.png)
Is there anyone who understands it better and can help explain how to interpret the acf and pacf?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLckA.png)